# How to add a new method to existing class using byte code manipulation?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

I need to add new (actually, override existing inherited) method in compiled java class. I can modify the method in superclass by using Instrumentation (`#retransformClasses()`) and Javassist (`#insertAfter()`). Unfortunately, that will change the behavior of all subclasses of that superclass but I want only the one particular class to be changed.

I can see Javaassist has `#addMethod()` functionality (and it actually works) but how to inject the resulting bytecode into JVM?

Both Java.Instrumentation `#retransformClasses()` and `#redefineClasses()` methods clearly say in javadocs:

> ...The redefinition must not add, remove or rename fields or methods...

Comment: Why can't you inherit and change your child?

Comment: I need to change behavior of existing app (not mine). My inherited child class will not be used by that app anyhow but will just exist aside. If it be so easy I would not deal with instrumentation at all...

Comment: This sounds very much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). You should focus on what you *really* want to do and change your question accordingly.

Comment: Not saying this is a better idea, but you could take the JAR of the existing app and replace a class file with a patched version.

Comment: More generally, you should modify the class *before* it is loaded for the first time. Can be done in the .jar file, or in a classloader or at any other point early in your program where the class is not yet used/loaded.